# Pointer's value is not an address?

Tags: c, cgi

I have a CGI script *(C program `test.elf`)* that gets called by GET method. This means that data is appended to url address that points to the same CGI script. For example:

```
http://.../cgi/c/test.elf?m=20&n=2000
```

Here we send data set `m=20&n=2000` which is sepparated from the rest of the url with a question mark `?`. Single variables in a data set are also sepparated with `&`. So actually we are sending `m=20` and `n=2000`.

CGI interface automatically stores sent data set `m=20&n=2000` in an enviromental variable `QUERY_STRING` for the time of the call and I want my CGI script to first print it's (a) value and (b) address.

This is the CGI script:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

    // getenv() returns a pointer to character (char*) and we need same type (char*) to store it.
    char* data;

    // We need an "array of characters" which is actualy the same as "string of characters".
    // Because strcpy() can only take pointer to the start of the array we also define another 
    // pointer and point it to array.
    char stored_enviromental_variable[1000];
    char* pointer;
    pointer = &stored_enviromental_variable[0];

    // ASCII HTML header
    printf("content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n");

    printf("<h1>Multiplication result</h1>");

    // Pointer now points to enviromental variable.
    data = getenv("QUERY_STRING");

    // We store the value of pointer
    strcpy(pointer, data);

    // We print some information.
    printf("%s: %s<br>", "Value of the \"QUERY_STRING\"", stored_enviromental_variable);
    printf("%s: %x<br>", "Address of the \"QUERY_STRING\"", data);

}
```

This compiles with a warning:

```
[ziga@localhost ~]$ gcc -Wpedantic -std=c18 -Wall -o test.elf test.c 
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:42:15: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("%s: %x<br>", "Address of the \"QUERY_STRING\"", data);
              ~^                                          ~~~~
              %s
```

So it looks like this source code is causing the problem:

```
printf("%s: %x<br>", "Address of the \"QUERY_STRING\"", data);
```

Which is weird to me, because I thought that *"pointer always stores location"*. So, why does `data` store a character? How can I remove the warning?

---

If I call the CGI script in the browser where I get this:

[image]

Comment: If you want to print the address that a pointer points to using `printf` you should use `%p`.

Comment: `data` doesn't store a `char`, it stores a *pointer* to `char` - it's an address value itself.  `%x` expects values of type `unsigned int`, not pointer types.  Passing arguments of the wrong type results in undefined behavior; gcc's being nice by issuing a warning, but it doesn't *have* to do so.  While a pointer value *may* be representable in an `unsigned int`, that's not guaranteed and is unlikely to be the case on modern 64-bit platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message states, the `%x` format specifier to `printf` expects an `unsigned int` argument, but you are instead passing in `data` whose type is `char *`.

To print a pointer value you should use the `%p` format specifier.  Also, the argument must be casted to `void *`:

```
printf("%s: %p<br>", "Address of the \"QUERY_STRING\"", (void *)data);
```

Comment: Now I remember I saw `%p` somewhere! Could you explain a bit further why do we need to *"cast the argument"* with `(void *)data`? This is the first time I see this syntax and I want to know what it means. I managed to compile without warning even if I didn't *"cast the argument"*. I only did `printf("%s: %p<br>", "Address of the \"QUERY_STRING\"", data);`

Comment: When used with “must be” in contemporary American English, the verb form of “cast” is simply “cast”: “must be cast.” Is it different in some other dialect?

Comment: @71GA The `%p` format specifier specifically expects a `void *`.  Pointers of any type can be implicitly converted to or from a `void *`, however `printf` is different because it is a variadic function.  This means this implicit conversion cannot occur by itself which is why the cast is necessary.  While many implementations use the same representation for all pointer types, that is not true in the general case.  So while you may get away with omitting the cast on some machines, on others you could have a problem.

Comment: @71GA *"Now I remember I saw %p somewhere!"*  the best place: "man printf" https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?printf(3